# How can i change scope of variable

Tags: javascript, push-notification

How can i change scope of `let result = [];`

```
const Notification = (res) => {
    let result = [];
    showNotification(notif => notif.map(res => { 
      result.push(res.date);
      console.log(result);
    }))
  };
```

This code returns dates and its ok

but when i put this, results returns undefined

```
const Notification = (res) => {
    let result = [];
    showNotification(notif => notif.map(res => { 
      result.push(res.date);
    }))
    console.log(result);
  };
```

this is a method showNotification, Im using react-native-push-notification

```
export const showNotification = (callback) => { 
  PushNotification.getScheduledLocalNotifications(callback);
}
```

sorry for my bad english

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to wait for the callback to resolve to get the result. Use async-await for asynchronous code. Let me know if it doesn't work.

```
export const showNotification = async (callback) => { 
  await PushNotification.getScheduledLocalNotifications(callback);
}

const Notification = async (res) => {
    let result = [];
    await showNotification(notif => notif.map(res => { 
      result.push(res.date);
    }))
    console.log(result);
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to assume what you mean by "return" here is how the variable is printed in the console, because you put `console.log` in different locations in the example you provided.

The reason why an empty array is printed in the second result is because the `showNotification` is an async function that accepts a closure as its parameter.

To put it simply, the order or execution in the function `showNotification` would be like the following

1. assign empty array to constant `result`
2. call `showNotification` by passing in a closure (which is the callback function) and `showNotification` returns immediately after calling `PushNotification.getScheduledLocalNotifications(callback)` (which I think is an async function)
3. call `console.log(result)` which prints an empty array
4. Some point later in time when the async function `PushNotification.getScheduledLocalNotifcations(callback)` executes the passed in callback function and appends it to the captured result array.

In the second block of code you provided, although `console.log(result)` is after the line where you call `showNotification()`, the closure passed in gets called in asynchronous manner so it is executed after `console.log(result)` is executed.